# What's this tag: Data?

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging

What's the point of the [data](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data)?  Can't really understand it's meaning.

Maybe consider to delete?

Since the word "data" - is very general and broad, I think it needs some moderation.

Maybe add some meaning to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are currently two questions with this tag - please just edit them to have different (better) tags.